# How can I pass a custom format to a NumberFormat inside an Mui TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using a Mui Textfield with the goal of having custom formats that I can pass into a prop. My issue is how can I pass custom formats. I have seen an online[sandbox:](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-br8l1?file=/src/index.js)
that implements [NumberFormat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format) inside a Mui TextField. But how do I pass in the format like this:

```
<div className="App">
  <TextField
    label="react-number-format"
    value={values.toFixed(2)}
    onChange={handleChange}
    name="numberformat"
    id="formatted-numberformat-input"
    InputProps={{
      inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom(format : '##-##-##')
    }}
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `format` parameter inside `inputProps` of `TextField` like this:

```
<TextField
    label="react-number-format"
    value={values.toFixed(2)}
    onChange={handleChange}
    name="numberformat"
    id="formatted-numberformat-input"
    inputProps={{ format: "##-##-##" }}
    InputProps={{
      inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom
    }}
/>
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-custom-format-q38c1y) for a live working example of this usage.

Comment: Anyone got this working with MUI5? Seems to be completely broken -- something about `refs`.